# Android resource linking failed AAPT: unknown option '--proguard-minimal-keep-rules'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, build-error

**My Android Studio was working fine, everything was good but after updating Android Studio to the latest version and updating gradle I got the following error**

Could you please provide the solution, thank you

Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{}],"original":"AAPT: unknown option '--proguard-minimal-keep-rules'.\n\naapt2 link [options] -o arg --manifest arg files...\n\nOptions:\n -o arg                                            Output path.\n --manifest arg                                    Path to the Android manifest to build.\n -I arg                                            Adds an Android APK to link against.\n -A arg                                            An assets directory to include in the APK. These are unprocessed.\n -R arg                                            Compilation unit to link, using `overlay` semantics.\n                                                   The last conflicting resource given takes precedence.\n --package-id arg                                  Specify the package ID to use for this app. Must be greater or equal to\n                                                   0x7f and can't be used with --static-lib or --shared-lib.\n --java arg                                        Directory in which to generate R.java.\n --proguard arg                                    Output file for generated Proguard rules.\n --proguard-main-dex arg                           Output file for generated Proguard rules for the main dex.\n --proguard-conditional-keep-rules                 Generate conditional Proguard keep rules.\n --no-auto-version                                 Disables automatic style and layout SDK versioning.\n --no-version-vectors                              Disables automatic versioning of vector drawables. Use this only\n                                                   when building with vector drawable support library.\n --no-version-transitions                          Disables automatic versioning of transition resources. Use this only\n                                                   when building with transition support library.\n --no-resource-deduping                            Disables automatic deduping of resources with\n                                                   identical values across compatible configurations.\n --enable-sparse-encoding                          This decreases APK size at the cost of resource retrieval performance.\n -x                                                Legacy flag that specifies to use the package identifier 0x01.\n -z                                                Require localization of strings marked 'suggested'.\n -c arg                                            Comma separated list of configurations to include. The default\n                                                   is all configurations.\n --preferred-density arg                           Selects the closest matching density and strips out all others.\n --product arg                                     Comma separated list of product names to keep\n --output-to-dir                                   Outputs the APK contents to a directory specified by -o.\n --no-xml-namespaces                               Removes XML namespace prefix and URI information\n                                                   from AndroidManifest.xml and XML binaries in res/*.\n --min-sdk-version arg                             Default minimum SDK version to use for AndroidManifest.xml.\n --target-sdk-version arg                          Default target SDK version to use for AndroidManifest.xml.\n --version-code arg                                Version code (integer) to inject into the AndroidManifest.xml if none is\n                                                   present.\n --version-code-major arg                          Version code major (integer) to inject into the AndroidManifest.xml if none is\n                                                   present.\n --version-name arg                                Version name to inject into the AndroidManifest.xml if none is present.\n --replace-version                                 If --version-code and/or --version-name are specified, these\n                                                   values will replace any value already in the manifest. By\n                                                   default, nothing is changed if the manifest already defines\n                                                   these attributes.\n --compile-sdk-version-code arg                    Version code (integer) to inject into the AndroidManifest.xml if none is\n                                                   present.\n --compile-sdk-version-name arg                    Version name to inject into the AndroidManifest.xml if none is present.\n --shared-lib                                      Generates a shared Android runtime library.\n --static-lib                                      Generate a static Android library.\n --proto-format                                    Generates compiled resources in Protobuf format.\n                                                   Suitable as input to the bundle tool for generating an App Bundle.\n --no-static-lib-packages                          Merge all library resources under the app's package.\n --non-final-ids                                   Generates R.java without the final modifier. This is implied when\n                                                   --static-lib is specified.\n --stable-ids arg                                  File containing a list of name to ID mapping.\n --emit-ids arg                                    Emit a file at the given path with a list of name to ID mappings,\n                                                   suitable for use with --stable-ids.\n --private-symbols arg                             Package name to use when generating R.java for private symbols.\n                                                   If not specified, public and private symbols will use the application's\n                                                   package name.\n --custom-package arg                              Custom Java package under which to generate R.java.\n --extra-packages arg                              Generate the same R.java but with different package names.\n --add-javadoc-annotation arg                      Adds a JavaDoc annotation to all generated Java classes.\n --output-text-symbols arg                         Generates a text file containing the resource symbols of the R class in\n                                                   the specified folder.\n --allow-reserved-package-id                       Allows the use of a reserved package ID. This should on be used for\n                                                   packages with a pre-O min-sdk\n                                                   \n --auto-add-overlay                                Allows the addition of new resources in overlays without\n                                                    tags.\n --rename-manifest-package arg                     Renames the package in AndroidManifest.xml.\n --rename-instrumentation-target-package arg       Changes the name of the target package for instrumentation. Most useful\n                                                   when used in conjunction with --rename-manifest-package.\n -0 arg                                            File extensions not to compress.\n --no-compress                                     Do not compress any resources.\n --warn-manifest-validation                        Treat manifest validation errors as warnings.\n --split arg                                       Split resources matching a set of configs out to a Split APK.\n                                                   Syntax: path/to/output.apk:[,[...]].\n                                                   On Windows, use a semicolon ';' separator instead.\n -v                                                Enables verbose logging.\n --debug-mode                                      Inserts android:debuggable=\"true\" in to the application node of the\n                                                   manifest, making the application debuggable even on production devices.\n --strict-visibility                               Do not allow overlays with different visibility levels.\n -h                                                Displays this help menu\n\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AAPT: unknown option '--proguard-minimal-keep-rules'.

aapt2 link [options] -o arg --manifest arg files...

Options:
 -o arg                                            Output path.
 --manifest arg                                    Path to the Android manifest to build.
 -I arg                                            Adds an Android APK to link against.
 -A arg                                            An assets directory to include in the APK. These are unprocessed.
 -R arg                                            Compilation unit to link, using `overlay` semantics.
                                                   The last conflicting resource given takes precedence.
 --package-id arg                                  Specify the package ID to use for this app. Must be greater or equal to
                                                   0x7f and can't be used with --static-lib or --shared-lib.
 --java arg                                        Directory in which to generate R.java.
 --proguard arg                                    Output file for generated Proguard rules.
 --proguard-main-dex arg                           Output file for generated Proguard rules for the main dex.
 --proguard-conditional-keep-rules                 Generate conditional Proguard keep rules.
 --no-auto-version                                 Disables automatic style and layout SDK versioning.
 --no-version-vectors                              Disables automatic versioning of vector drawables. Use this only
                                                   when building with vector drawable support library.
 --no-version-transitions                          Disables automatic versioning of transition resources. Use this only
                                                   when building with transition support library.
 --no-resource-deduping                            Disables automatic deduping of resources with
                                                   identical values across compatible configurations.
 --enable-sparse-encoding                          This decreases APK size at the cost of resource retrieval performance.
 -x                                                Legacy flag that specifies to use the package identifier 0x01.
 -z                                                Require localization of strings marked 'suggested'.
 -c arg                                            Comma separated list of configurations to include. The default
                                                   is all configurations.
 --preferred-density arg                           Selects the closest matching density and strips out all others.
 --product arg                                     Comma separated list of product names to keep
 --output-to-dir                                   Outputs the APK contents to a directory specified by -o.
 --no-xml-namespaces                               Removes XML namespace prefix and URI information
                                                   from AndroidManifest.xml and XML binaries in res/*.
 --min-sdk-version arg                             Default minimum SDK version to use for AndroidManifest.xml.
 --target-sdk-version arg                          Default target SDK version to use for AndroidManifest.xml.
 --version-code arg                                Version code (integer) to inject into the AndroidManifest.xml if none is
                                                   present.
 --version-code-major arg                          Version code major (integer) to inject into the AndroidManifest.xml if none is
                                                   present.
 --version-name arg                                Version name to inject into the AndroidManifest.xml if none is present.
 --replace-version                                 If --version-code and/or --version-name are specified, these
                                                   values will replace any value already in the manifest. By
                                                   default, nothing is changed if the manifest already defines
                                                   these attributes.
 --compile-sdk-version-code arg                    Version code (integer) to inject into the AndroidManifest.xml if none is
                                                   present.
 --compile-sdk-version-name arg                    Version name to inject into the AndroidManifest.xml if none is present.
 --shared-lib                                      Generates a shared Android runtime library.
 --static-lib                                      Generate a static Android library.
 --proto-format                                    Generates compiled resources in Protobuf format.
                                                   Suitable as input to the bundle tool for generating an App Bundle.
 --no-static-lib-packages                          Merge all library resources under the app's package.
 --non-final-ids                                   Generates R.java without the final modifier. This is implied when
                                                   --static-lib is specified.
 --stable-ids arg                                  File containing a list of name to ID mapping.
 --emit-ids arg                                    Emit a file at the given path with a list of name to ID mappings,
                                                   suitable for use with --stable-ids.
 --private-symbols arg                             Package name to use when generating R.java for private symbols.
                                                   If not specified, public and private symbols will use the application's
                                                   package name.
 --custom-package arg                              Custom Java package under which to generate R.java.
 --extra-packages arg                              Generate the same R.java but with different package names.
 --add-javadoc-annotation arg                      Adds a JavaDoc annotation to all generated Java classes.
 --output-text-symbols arg                         Generates a text file containing the resource symbols of the R class in
                                                   the specified folder.
 --allow-reserved-package-id                       Allows the use of a reserved package ID. This should on be used for
                                                   packages with a pre-O min-sdk

--auto-add-overlay                                Allows the addition of new resources in overlays without
                                                    tags.
 --rename-manifest-package arg                     Renames the package in AndroidManifest.xml.
 --rename-instrumentation-target-package arg       Changes the name of the target package for instrumentation. Most useful
                                                   when used in conjunction with --rename-manifest-package.
 -0 arg                                            File extensions not to compress.
 --no-compress                                     Do not compress any resources.
 --warn-manifest-validation                        Treat manifest validation errors as warnings.
 --split arg                                       Split resources matching a set of configs out to a Split APK.
                                                   Syntax: path/to/output.apk:[,[...]].
                                                   On Windows, use a semicolon ';' separator instead.
 -v                                                Enables verbose logging.
 --debug-mode                                      Inserts android:debuggable="true" in to the application node of the
                                                   manifest, making the application debuggable even on production devices.
 --strict-visibility                               Do not allow overlays with different visibility levels.
 -h                                                Displays this help menu

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem after updating AS and grade plugin, the problem is with Gradle version 6.1.1 try downgrading to the latest stable one from the project structure till the release of another Gradle version.
Go to -
file -> project structure
[image]

Comment: Yes it works. I downgraded my Android Gradle Plugin Version from 4.0.0 to  3.6.3. and the kept gradle version as 6.1.1  only.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue
Try these basic solutions:
(Check if it works after trying every solution)

1. File->Invalidate Cache and restart
2. Build -> clean project.
3. Delete the build folder from your code.
4. Make sure that you have updated all dependencies in the project-level Gradle

   file.

Comment: Thank you for answer but still the same problem.